# What is the best way to word a description of a dinner special with options

Tags: conjunctions, lists, coordinating-conjunctions, correlative-conjunctions

My family recently ordered takeout from a local restaurant. My brother, father and I ordered the dinner special. This special included five side dishes, three of which were determined by the restaurant. To complete our order we had to make two decisions, each between two choices. My brother and I understood the way the restaurant worded this, but my father interpreted it differently and insisted they had written the description of the special incorrectly.

Here is the original description:

> All dinners are served with markouk, rice, baba
>   ghanooj or hummus, and tabouli or Lebanese
>   salad.

To clarify, this was the only description of the dinner besides a list of main course options. The total number of side dishes was not specified anywhere.

After some discussion, here is the potential alternative we came up with:

> All dinners are served with markouk, rice, either baba
>   ghanooj or hummus, and either tabouli or Lebanese
>   salad.

Is the original description worded incorrectly? Is our alternative correct? If not, what would the correct wording be, keeping in mind that space on the menu is limited.

Comment: What is the argument for the description being incorrect?

Comment: Definitely on your dad's side here; the only way it's possible to determine the correct organization of the sentence is by knowing ahead of time how many items are included. I've found three completely different interpretations no one's mentioned yet.

Comment: Assuming the commas to be correct, then: “*All dinners are served with (i) markouk, (ii) rice, and (iii) baba ghanooj or hummus, and (iv) tabouli or Lebanese salad.*” ++ The “agreed version” is thus “*All dinners are served with (i) markouk, (ii) rice, and **either** (iii) baba ghanooj or hummus, and **either** (iv) tabouli or Lebanese salad.*” ++ All you have done is added “either” which is not necessary. That said, I think yours emphasises the choices but the spoken/read out loud versions are about the same as intonation can be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original description is certainly less clear than it might be. I could reasonably parse the list in a couple of ways:

- markouk and rice and (baba ghanooj or hummus) and (tabouli or Lebanese salad)

or

- (markouk and rice and baba ghanooj) or (hummus and tabouli) or Lebanese salad.

I think most people would probably figure out the correct option.

Your sentence is certainly clearer and leaves little room for misinterpretation. You might also achieve the same effect with punctuation:

- markouk; rice; baba ghanooj or hummus; and tabouli or Lebanese salad.

Comment: The punctuation of the original sentence makes the second reading quite unlikely. Also, to avoid confusing future visitors to this page, it should perhaps be said that the parentheses are used in this answer in the way they are used in mathematics and logic, not the way they are normally used in English. (The answer presumably does not recommend that the sentence actually be written with the parentheses.)

Comment: There’s always the semi-colon.